# C++ linkedList head returns NULL even though list is not empty

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the pop function of a linked list in C++. My Node and Linked List classes look like this:

```
//Node class 
template <class T> 
class Node{
    public:
        T data; 
        Node<T> *next;

        Node(T data, Node<T> *next);
        ~Node();
};

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T data, Node<T> *next){
    this->next = next;
    this->data = data;
}

template <class T>
Node<T>::~Node(){
    delete this;
}

//LinkedList class
template <class T> 
class  LinkedList{ 
    public:
        //fields
        Node<T> *head;
        int size;

        //methods
        LinkedList();
        void push(T data);
        T pop();   
        void printList();

};

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){
    this->head = NULL;
    this->size = 0;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::printList(){
    int i = 1;
    while(head){
        std::cout<<i<<": "<<head->data<<std::endl;
        head = head->next;
        i++;
    }
}

int main(){ 
    LinkedList<int> list;

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i)
        list.push(i);

    list.printList();

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        int output=list.pop();
        printf("popped: %d\n", output);
    }

    list.printList();
    return 0;
}
```

Below is my pop function. The problem is that this->head is returning NULL. hence I cannot change its value or access its data field. I used print statements to find out that this->head is returning NULL. How can I resolve this issue?

```
template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::pop(){
    Node<T> *h = this->head;

    //if list is empty
    if (this->size==0){
        return 0;
    }

    //if list has only one node
    if (this->size==1){
        T ret = h->data; 
        this->head = NULL;
        this->size --; 
        return ret; 
    }

    //if list has multiple nodes
    else{
        T ret = this->head->data;
        this -> head = h->next;
        return ret;
    }

    h.~Node<T>();

}
```

Below if my push function. I have tested this function and it works fine, but please let me know if it is not handling node pointers properly.

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::push(T data){
    Node<T> *n = new Node<T>(data, this->head);
    this->head = n;
    this->size++;   
}
```

Comment: *h.~Node<T>();* compiles for you? Anyway, why do you call destructor explicitly like that, what is the purpose?

Comment: I defined a function for ~Node<T>() which I did not include. I was trying to stop a memory leak by freeing the node pointer *h, but now that I look at my code, I am not sure if I need it at all. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: *I was trying to stop a memory leak* -- You stop the memory leak by properly handling the resources in your class, not by explicitly calling the destructor.

Comment: Recommend a read through of [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to reduce future problems.

Comment: `push` looks good assuming `Node(T data, Node<T> *next)` is good and `LinkedList();` sets `head` to `NULL`.

Comment: For your actual problem I think we need a [mcve].

Comment: I have added the necessary functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class T>
Node<T>::~Node(){
    delete this;
}
```

This is so very very wrong. You need to get rid of it completely.

More importantly, `printList()` is modifying `head` when it shouldn't be. That is why `head` is NULL when `pop()` is called. Use a local `Node*` variable to iterate the list:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::printList(){
    int i = 1;
    Node<T> *n = head; // <-- here
    while(n){
        std::cout << i << ": " << n->data << std::endl;
        n = n->next;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Also, `pop()` is not freeing nodes correctly (if at all), and not always decrementing `size`.  It should look more like this instead:

```
template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::pop(){
    Node<T> *h = this->head;

    //if list is empty
    if (this->size==0){
        return T(); // <-- not 0! or throw an exception instead...
    }

    //if list has only one node
    if (this->size==1){
        T ret = h->data; 
        this->head = NULL;
        this->size--; 
        delete h; // <-- add this!
        return ret; 
    }

    //if list has multiple nodes

    T ret = this->head->data;
    this->head = h->next;
    this->size--; // <-- add this!

    delete h; // <-- not h.~Node<T>()!

    return ret; // <-- moved down here!
}
```

Or simpler, this (no need to handle the `size==1` case separately):

```
template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::pop(){
    Node<T> *h = this->head;

    //if list is empty
    if (!h){
        return T();
    }

    //if list has any nodes

    T ret = h->data;
    this->head = h->next;
    this->size--;
    delete h;

    return ret;
}
```